# dimple.js: unequal time periods and missing labels

Tags: charts, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have a date data series with uneven periods between data points. I want to have a label for each data point in the series. Any ideas how to archieve it?

Fiddle link is [here](http://bit.ly/1m1auaI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to promote my comment to an answer, one way to accomplish your mission would be to employ  [d3 axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) to more rigidly control the axis.  I updated John's jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tf3Sk/4/) to demonstrate how we can do this.  The full standalone code is below and in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/db285de282e9a47f5bed).

```
  <div id="volumeReport">

  <script>
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#volumeReport", 590, 500);
    var data = [
    {"Date": "22/7/2014", "Volume" : 0},
    {"Date": "15/11/2014", "Volume" : 1000},
    {"Date": "5/01/2015", "Volume" : 2000},
    {"Date": "5/2/2015", "Volume" : 3000},
    {"Date": "31/3/2015", "Volume" : 4000}
    ];
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Date", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%L", "%d-%m-%Y");
    x.addOrderRule("Date");
    x.timeField = "Date";
    x.dateParseFormat = "%d/%m/%Y";
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Volume");
    var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.area);
    s.interpolation = "step";
    s.lineWeight = 1;
    s.lineMarkers = true;
    myChart.draw();

    myChart.axes[0].shapes.call(
      d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("bottom")
        .scale(myChart.axes[0]._scale)
        .tickValues(data.map(function(d,i){
            return d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse(d.Date)
          })
        )
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"))
    )
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A category axis will evenly space the dates along the axis:

```
myChart.addCategoryAxis("Date");
```

It also looks like you were trying to use a step area chart which requires version 2.1 of dimple.  I've updated the version in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tf3Sk/1/

Comment: The distances between data points are not equal and I'd like to keep the previous value until a new one appears. 

I've updates the fiddle with more plausible values:
http://jsfiddle.net/tf3Sk/2/

Comment: in that case I think it's just the version that's wrong, is this what you are after (it's your original code running in v2.1) http://jsfiddle.net/tf3Sk/3/

Comment: If you want a label on the x axis for each point rather than at regular intervals I'm afraid the library can't do that

Comment: Would it be possible to archieve it by iterating dimple.series.shapes and using d3?

Comment: Yeah I guess if you remove the text from the axis and then draw it again for each point: http://jsfiddle.net/tf3Sk/4/

Comment: alternately you could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/timelyportfolio/tx6PR/

Comment: Do that, it's better than my suggestion

Comment: Thanks @timelyportfolio! If you make your comment an answer I'll change accepted answer to yours.